# How to replicate a nested Dictionary structure in C# to Lua

Tags: c#, dictionary, lua, nested, lua-table

I was trying to work with Tables in Lua and wanted to replicate a piece of code of mine from C# to it. Therein I had used a nested Dictionary to get the things done but I'm unable to achieve the same in Lua.

This is the C# code that I'm trying to replicate

```
public class FBDetails
{
     public double ElapsedTime { get; set; }
     public double AFB{ get; set; }
}
    
public void AddFBDetails(Dictionary<double, Dictionary<DateTime, List<FBDetails>>> Dict, double FR, DateTime ET, double ElapsedTime, double FB)
{
    if (!Dict.ContainsKey(FR))
    {
        Dict.Add(FR, new Dictionary<DateTime, List<FBDetails>>());
    }

    if (!Dict[FR].ContainsKey(ET))
    {   
        Dict[FR].Add(ET, new List<FBDetails>());
        Dict[FR][ET].Add(new FBDetails() {ElapsedTime = ElapsedTime, ActiveFB = FB});
    }
    else
    {
        Dict[FR][ET].Add(new FBDetails() {ElapsedTime = ElapsedTime, ActiveFB = FB});
    }
}
```

The Lua code that I have written so far (which I know is wrong) is down below. PS: I'n not very well accustomed to Functions in Lua as of now so was just focusing on getting the data structure right but I will appreciate if anyone can help with the function bit as well.

```
Dict = {} 

if Dict[FR] == nil then
    Dict { [FR] = {} }
end

if Dict[FR][ET] == nil then
    Dict[FR] = { [ET] = {} }
    Dict[FR] = { [ET] = { {ElapsedTime}, {FB} } } 
else
    Dict[FR] = { [ET] = { {ElapsedTime}, {FB} } } 
end
```

Comment: `Dict[FR] = { [ET] = { {ElapsedTime}, {FB} } }` only need this line and not the rest even the `else`

Comment: For a particular value of FR which is my first key and ET which is the key of the second table, I will have multiple distinct values of ElapsedTime and FB which are being streamed at a frequency of 1 second. The idea behind the above Lua code was that first, I will check that if there is any value associated to the key FR, in case there is I will then check if there is value linked to ET. If yes, then I want to add the Elapsed Time and FB to the previously existing tables corresponding to FR and ET. Will I be able to achieve that with what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lua code is wiping out previous entries, this is because you are not setting the value properly.

When you do:

```lua
Dict[FR] = { [ET] = { {ElapsedTime}, {FB} } }
```

you are essentially removing all other entries in `FR` and in `ET`, this is because you are redefining the value at `FR` when you say `Dict[FR] = {...`

The same is true when you do:

```lua
Dict = { [FR] = {} }
```

You're redefining `Dict` wiping out all other entries other then the current `FR`

---

Your lua should be indexing the value before the `=`. It can also be simplified.

```lua
function AddFBDetails(Dict, FR, ET, ElapsedTime, FB)
  if Dict[FR] == nil then
      Dict[FR] = {[ET] = {}}
  elseif Dict[FR][ET] == nil then
    Dict[FR][ET] = {}
  end

  table.insert(Dict[FR][ET], { {ElapsedTime}, {FB} })
end
```

Comment: What about the functionality of adding data into a class list? Like in my C# script, I'm doing this:  `Dict[FR][ET].Add(new FBDetails() {ElapsedTime = ElapsedTime, ActiveFB = FB});` This enables to access Values of ElapsedTime and ActiveFB at a later stage by traversing through the dictionary and then running a for loop and doing something like this: `double FB = Data[k].ActiveFB;` I'm afraid that similar thing is not possible in Lua or is it?

Comment: If I understand you correctly yes it is possible to do what you said in Lua, if `Data` represents some `Dict[FR][ET]` then you use `ipairs` to get each table from inside the `ET` and index the value to get your `FB`. This syntax `{ {ElapsedTime}, {FB} }` does not make it easy but it can be changed to`{ ElapsedTime = ElapsedTime, ActiveFB = FB }` where the text before the `=` is the key

Comment: Yes, `{ ElapsedTime = ElapsedTime, ActiveFB = FB }` will help the cause. Thanks!